# CSS translate with vw doesn't work on iOS < 8, workaround?

Tags: ios, css, mobile

Apparently doing `transform: translate` with `vw` units doesn't work on iOS < 8.

Here is a demo, comparing translate %, which works on both mobile and non-mobile, and vw which only works on iOS 8+ and non-mobile:

http://codepen.io/rachel-carvalho/pen/azmoPJ?editors=110

```
#p {
  -webkit-transform: translate(10%, 0);
  transform: translate(10%, 0);
}

#vw {
  -webkit-transform: translate(10vw, 0);
  transform: translate(10vw, 0);
}
```

I don't know if other mobile devices have a problem translating vw, but I can't find anything on the web about this problem.

I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem and if there's a reliable way to detect this behavior, so I can workaround with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in past with vmax,**vw** for some browsers(specially IE)
and got to know that it does support but their is a partial support for that sometimes it may work some times it may not ,
[Check here](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw)

For that you can use a jquery library which convert vw to px dynamically **buggyfill**.js

Hope it will work for you !

Comment: caniuse.com only reports problems on iOS 7 using vh, it says nothing about vw problems, so I don't know if buggy fill would solve my problem.